# DNS problem, old dns servers are not going away

Tags: windows-7, dns, nameserver

I have a [website](http://www.strp.net), and I changed the nameservers of the domain of my site, now people see it with my new nameservers however I still see the oldnameservers (Which are sedo's nameservers).

I tried ipconfig/flushdns it works and clears the caches, however when I enter the domain the cache restores back with the old nameservers.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can take up to several days for DNS changes to propagate across the Internet. (If, for instance, your domain's record had had a time-to-live of a week before you edited it, it will take a week for remote servers to consider the record obsolete and request a new copy.)

If I understand you when you say "now people see it with my new nameservers, however I still see the old nameservers" correctly, this disparity merely means that the name servers you're using haven't received the changes yet.

If the problem still exists tomorrow, I would suggest that you call your ISP and ask them if they can force a DNS update for you.

Comment: "this disparity merely means that the name servers you're using haven't received the changes yet." possibly because of this, and I entered DNSs servers of google manually and it worked. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

As Goblinbox pointed out, its likely that your ISP's DNS server is serving you the old cached `A record`, others are likely accessing a different DNS server which is why they can see it with the new name servers.

Your ISPs DNS records should catch up soon, if you want to be able to access your website while you wait for your ISP to update, then setup windows-7 or your `web-browser` to use a custom DNS.

Some you can try:

- [Google Public DNS](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/)
- [Open DNS](http://www.opendns.com/)

Step 6 on this [Microsoft Page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Change-TCP-IP-settings) shows how to configure a custom DNS system wide.

*As a side note, I have found that the Google Public DNS servers have an equal if not better response time than the DNS servers provided by many ISPs.*

Comment: @sprsr, I didn't see your comment- that you had already tried and been successful with Google Public DNS, glad you have it resolved :-)